# How to use one class variable in another class in python

Tags: python, class

How to access variable from one class to another class. Lets say class A has argument given from command line. I want to access the variable of class A give through command line to another class say class B.How to access?

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,var1,var2):
        pass
class B():
    def __call__(self):
        #(here I want to use var1 and var2 from class A)

A(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: You could inherit B from A, or pass an instance of A to B when constructing it. Whether or not to inherit B from A may depend on how functionally similar B is to A. It's probably easier (and, without context, more logical), to pass an instance of A to the constructor of B.

Comment: `def __call__(self):` or `def __init__(self):?` That's quite a difference.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "use"? Do something with the same arguments a particular instance of `A` was constructed with?

Comment: Also what do you think the line `A(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])` is doing?

Comment: "I want to access the variable of class A give through command line to another class" These arguments are still stored in `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]`, so why not just use them again?

Comment: Thanks. But if I want to use sys.argv in a method which is inside a class B how to do??

Answer (score 3):

Either

```
import sys
class A():
    def __init__(self,var1,var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        pass
class B():
    def __call__(self, a):
        print(a.var1, a.var2)
        #(here I want to use var1 and var2 from class A)

a = A(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
b = B()
b(a)
```

Or

```
import sys
class A():
    def __init__(self,var1,var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        pass
class B():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __call__(self):
        print(self.a.var1, self.a.var2)
        #(here I want to use var1 and var2 from class A)

a = A(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
b = B(a)
b()
```

use One among these two based on use case

Answer (score 0):

Since `var1` and `var2` are instance variables, you could send the instance of class `A` to class `B`:

```
import sys

class A():
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2

class B():        
    def __call__(self, A):
        self.var1 = A.var1
        self.var2 = A.var2

obj_one = A(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
obj_two = B()

obj_two(obj_one)

print(obj_two.var1)
print(obj_two.var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First create instance variables for `class A` by changing its definition as follows

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,var1,var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
```

and then pass the instance of `class A` to `__call__` method of `class B`
as follows

```
class B():
    def __init__(self, class_A_object):
        self.var1 = class_A_object.var1
        self.var2 = class_A_object.var2
```

Now you can use the `var1` and `var2` of `class B` anywhere inside the instance you created.

```
object_a = A(var1, var2)
object_b = B(object_a)
print object_b.var1, object_b.var2
```